# Pandas - Merging data from multiple rows into a single row

Tags: pandas, pandas-apply

I am trying to merge data from multiple rows into a single row.

```
df.groupby('issue')['name'].apply(' '.join).reset_index()
```

But I am getting an error : `TypeError: unhashable type: 'Issue'`

Given below is how my data looks like :

```
issue, name
101,prod_a
101,prod_b
102,prod_b
103,prod_a
103,prod_c
```

Expected output:

```
issue, new_val
101, prod_a,prod_b
102, prod_b
103, prod_a, prod_c
```

Comment: you forget `groupby` - `df.groupby('issue')['name'].apply(' '.join).reset_index()`

Comment: @jezrael, sorry my bad missed to add the group by when I was asking the question. I have updated my initial post with my comments.

Comment: @jezrael, thank you I figured where I was wrong, managed to get this fixed.